# What are the phylosophical implications of the definitions of life?

Tags: life, definitions, philosophy-of-biology

What are the philosophical implications of having life defined somehow? How can our worldview be affected by the definition of life we accept?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. This seems a little broad. Generally, good questions are answerable in a few paragraphs. Could you tighten the scope a little? For more information, see the [tour] and [ask]. Cheers.